# Mongoose dynamic schema type based on other field value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, validation, mongoose

Let say I have the following schema:

```js
new Schema({
  fruitType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'mango'],
    required: true,
  },
  fruitValue: [ appleSchema ],
})
```

When the `fruitType` is apple, I want the `fruitValue` to be `appleSchema` and when it is melon, I want the field to have `melonSchema`. Is there a way in Mongoose to achieve this?